# Is there any reason to keep my Screaming Demon Ring?

Tags: the-secret-world

I stopped getting the bonus experience from this before I ever left Kingsmouth (I was informed you could tell when you stopped getting the experience because the preorder pet stops giving a buff at around the same point) and it was quickly exceeded in stats for the slot as well.  So, I haven't been wearing it for quite some time now.

Is there any reason for me to hold onto this item, or should I just toss it?  Can I reobtain one if I feel like I have a need for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can toss it without a problem if you find a ring with better stats on it. It has no use after you lose the exp bonus. But if you do delete it there is no way of getting it back. But why would you? Since it is only useful for the stats and exp.

If you do want to use it on another character the ring is obtainable for every character the same way you got it.

Comment: What if I want it for sentimental value or to show off my preorder?  No way to get it back on the *same* character?

Comment: @Shinrai Nope, once you delete it, it is gone. Except maybe if you ask a GM nicely they will return it. But other then that your stuck. But if you want to show off your pre order why not do it with the pet? If you are wearing the ring then need to inspect you, the pet just follows you around letting people see you pre ordered it. For sentimental value you can just store it in your bank?